# Dosen't my computer has other partitions mounted?

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, mountpoint

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 loaded on my machine. I recently got a little mixed up and have made new partitions by making the others a little small. But now I have to delete them but not finding the way. I know my root directory which I should not delete and searching for all the other important partitions but I cannot get them as only root is stated.
This is the result of `lsblk /dev/sda`

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0   6.9G  0 part 
├─sda3    8:3    0  35.6G  0 part 
├─sda5    8:5    0   3.7G  0 part 
├─sda6    8:6    0    47G  0 part 
├─sda7    8:7    0  13.7G  0 part 
├─sda8    8:8    0 103.5G  0 part /
├─sda9    8:9    0   6.8G  0 part 
└─sda10   8:10   0   5.4G  0 part
```

Comment: Run `gparted` and see.

Comment: I have already used it but it shows only root point

Answer (score 0):

The [gparted](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/gparted.8.html) or [disks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Disks) apps on an [Ubuntu LiveUSB](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0) allow you to delete partitions. It also allows you to increase existing partition size to use the space of the deleted partitions. However, you can't resize anything on the same drive you booted from (hence the LiveUSB).

**Back Up Your Data** before doing this!

Do not delete and resize in the same action; tell the app to delete a partition, then tell the app to go ahead and do it, before you resize to regain the newly available space.

Do not move the boot partition, and do not delete the partition where GRUB's data is. Either is a sure way to make your system unbootable.

Here's an article illustrating how to [use gparted](https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted) for this job.

Comment: 1 thing is still left, How do I know where is the boot partition as the result of ```lsblk /dev/sda``` was the above and it didn't state any boot partition and also not any swap partition but I have one as the result of ```swapon --show``` is showing me results

Comment: You probably don’t have a swap partition. Ubuntu 18.04 normally uses a swap file

Comment: Yes, the swap file, but how do I know which partition is the boot partition as the result of ```lsblk /dev/sda``` is not showing any boot partition as you can see in the above question